# javascript wrap caret position within tags in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript

I am developing a wysiwyg where the user can inject text at any position by using some external buttons.

I am using the code provided by bloodyKnuckles in this answer: [Split a HTML tag with contents at caret position into multiple tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73761074/split-a-html-tag-with-contents-at-caret-position-into-multiple-tags/77507756#77507756)

This code does not work if the div contains `<br>` and the caret is in a new lines.

here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gntvycxa/1/

After working on it for long time, I come to the conclusion that I need to surround the caret with a tag (example `<span></span>`) in order to have it inside a node.

The problem is that the function receives target and currentTarget `function({target, currentTarget})` , all tags are closed and I do not know how to manipulate the target.

The steps should be:

- surround the caret with a tag
- insert the new node inside the target at caret position

How can I do it ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have created https://jsfiddle.net/gntvycxa/1/